# Heavy writing in cassandra cluster causes a node to fail

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have to read a massive amount of table entries that I want to write to another table. Therefore I wrote a java+scala program that uses an rdd to scan the source table and write each entry in the target table. The program is submitted to a spark cluster that is connected to a cassandra cluster, both located in amazon, with the following settings:

- Spark cluster has one master and four slaves with 8 cores each and 16gb of ram
- cassandra cluster has three nodes with 8 cores each, 32gb of ram, standart hdds yielding the source and target tables and an sdd for the commit log.

The keyset is distributed by the three cassandra nodes which means that this cluster is not fault tolerant. Everything works fine in the first 8-16 hours and the resource usage does not seem to indicate that cassandra might be overloaded (at least not at first, not sure overnight).

Unfortunately, after several hours one node ends with an inconsistent schema version and therefore the cluster fails. I am trying to determine which are the possible causes for this to happen, any advice is most welcome!

Thank you for your time

---

More configuration details as requested:

concurrent_compactors: Default (Smaller of number of disks or number of cores, with a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 8 per CPU core)

compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: Default (16)

compaction strategy: Default (size tiered compaction strategy)

Comment: Is there any other errors in system.log prior to schema version inconsistency? What are concurrent_compactors and compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec parameters in the config? What is compaction strategy of the table you are talking about?